# How to make a checkmark function in a way that users cannot spam and have a bunch of checkmarks beside their name in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

It's me again, back with another inquiry. I got my code up and running after fixing the errors, and all seems well. But the problem is, I quickly found out that guild members could easily take advantage of the command and spam it to get a whole bunch of checkmarks. I need a way to stop that from happening. For now, I'm thinking of a if and return function, but I do not know what to put in between the if and the return.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.content == '*verify check') {
  message.member
   .setNickname(`${message.member.displayName} ✅`)
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  message.react('✅');
  console.log(`Successfully verified ${message.member}`);
 }
});
```

Comment: SO is not a discord clone -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if their nickname already ends with a checkmark before changing it with `String.prototype.endsWith()`

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content == "*verify check") {
    if (messge.member.displayName.endsWith("✅"))
      return message.channel.send(
        "Your display name already ends with a checkmark!"
      );
    message.member
      .setNickname(`${message.member.displayName} ✅`)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    message.react("✅");
    console.log(`Successfully verified ${message.member}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It will certainly result in server members not going insane with the command haha. Have a nice day!